# How can I serve 2 Django applications in different virtual environments on Apache Windows?

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I currently have two Django apps running on the server with no virtual environments (not a good idea - it was a rookie mistake). I now have to differentiate their environments due to some dependency differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `WSGIDaemonProcess` is not available on Windows I managed it the following way in Wamp:

This is the relevant part of my httpd.conf:

```
WSGIPythonPath "C:/wamp/www"

WSGIScriptAlias /im "C:/wamp/www/im/im/wsgi.py"

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/im/im">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /im/static/ "C:/wamp/www/im/im/static_root/"

WSGIScriptAlias /tggs "C:/wamp/www/tggs/tggs/wsgi.py"

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/tggs/tggs">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /tggs/static/ "C:/wamp/www/tggs/static_root/"
```

As you might have guessed my two Django apps are called "im" and "tggs". There is nothing about virtualenv at this point. Following is the `wsgi.py` of the application "tggs" which I want to run in virtualenv in `C:\pyenv\tggs18`

```
import os
import sys
import site

ALLDIRS = ["C:\pyenv\tggs18\Lib\site-packages"]

# Add each new site-packages directory.
for directory in ALLDIRS:
    site.addsitedir(directory)

sys.path.append("C:/wamp/www/tggs/tggs")
sys.path.append("C:/wamp/www/tggs")

activate_env_file = "C:\\pyenv\\tggs18\\Scripts\\activate_this.py"
execfile(activate_env_file, dict(__file__=activate_env_file))

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "tggs.settings"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

You should also check:

- http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/
- https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments